# How do I remove a words ending in the letter S if duplicates without an S on the end are on the same list?

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, awk, sed, perl

I have a large list of words. Many of the words are only different because they have the letter s on the end. If a word on the list is the exact same as another word on the list, except one of the words ends with the letter s, I would like to remove the duplicate word that ends in s. I would also like to accomplish this without having to sort the list so that I can maintain the current position of the words.

example input:

```
frog
dogs
cats
cat
dog
frogs
catfish
octopus
```

example output:

```
frog
cat
dog
catfish
octopus
```

Comment: Do you want to keep lines that are plural but don't have a singular counterpart ?

Comment: I'd like to preserve the current sort order and eliminate the words ending in s. I'd like to keep the singular form. If there is a word ending in s I would like to check to see if there is the same word exists elsewhere on the list. If the word does exist, I'd like to eliminate the word ending in s.

Comment: @123 how would you handle an octopus?

Comment: @J363, you didn't answer 123's question: add "horses" to this list *without* "horse" -- should you output "horses"?

Comment: According to your sample data and criteria, `sed '/s$/d'` would work.

Comment: @glennjackman in the event that horse is not on the list, horses should remain, for the exact same situation Chris H is postulating.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using awk and reading the file twice. Save all variables in array with s on the end. Check the array on each line in the second run through and print if the line is not in array.

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$0 "s"]++;next}!($0 in a)' file.txt file.txt
```

To use a little less memory you could also do

```
awk 'FNR==NR{!/s$/ && a[$0 "s"]++;next}!($0 in a)' file.txt file.txt
```

Comment: When I pass these commands I seem to be getting no output? I'm not sure if I'm doing something wrong on my end.

Comment: @J363, what if you use `file.txt file.txt` in place of `test{,}`?  (By the way, 123, I like brace expansion a lot but I usually omit it in answers in favor of better clarity and readability.  Just a suggestion.)

Comment: @Wildcard I have edited, thanks for the tip.

Comment: @123 This works wonderfully, thank you again. Is there any way you can tell me how to get the inverse output so I can see what your tool is going to remove before I go ahead and finalize the change by writing to a new file? I've been sorting and using comm to compare files but doing so is extremely inefficient.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this in several ways, e.g., the simplest way would be to sort the data and compare adjacent lines:

```
sort foo |awk '{ if ( plural[$1] == "" ) print; plural[$1 "s"] = 1; }'
```

Given input

```
frog
dogs
cats
catfish
cat
dog
frogs
```

output

```
cat
catfish
dog
frog
```

Without sorting:

```
#!/bin/sh
awk 'BEGIN { count=0; }
{
        words[count++] = $1;
        plurals[$1 "s"] = $1;
}
END {
        for ( n = 0; n < count; ++n) {
                if ( plurals[words[n]] == "")
                        print words[n];
        }
}
' <foo
```

Output:

```
frog
catfish
cat
dog
```

Comment: What about if another animal has the same start of the name? E.g `cat` and `catfish`.

Answer (score 3):

Using a bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

readarray -t mylist

# compare each item on the list with a new list created by appending `s'
# to each item of the original list

for i in "${mylist[@]}"; do
  for j in "${mylist[@]/%/s}"; do
    [[ "$i" == "$j" ]] && continue 2
  done
  echo "$i"
done
```

The list is read from stdin. Here is a test run:

```
$ cat file1
frog
dogs
cats
cat
dog
frogs
catfish
$ ./remove-s.sh < file1 
frog
cat
dog
catfish
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a simplified solution using `awk`, which does not preserve the order of words:

```
    {
        len = length($1);
        prefix = $1;
        if (substr($1, len) == "s") {
            prefix = substr($1, 1, len - 1);
        }
        if (prefix in data) {
            next;
        } else {
            print prefix;
            data[prefix] = 1;
        }
    }
```

If it is essential to preserve the order of words, then you will have to keep all lines in memory and process the list after the entire file has been read.

```
{
    line[FNR] = $0;
    len = length($1);
    if (substr($1, len) == "s") {
        prefix = substr($1, 1, len - 1);
        if (prefix in data) {
            line[FNR] = "";
            next;
        } else {
            data[prefix] = FNR;
        }
    } else {
        num = data[$1];
        if (num) {
            line[num] = "";
        } else {
            data[$1] = FNR;
        }
    }
}

END {
    for (i = 1; i <= FNR; i++) {
        if (line[i]) {
            print line[i];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

With excessive use of grep's `-f` (obtain patterns from file) option:

```
grep 's$' input       | # output: all lines ending with s 
  sed -e 's/s$//'     | # those same entries, minus the s
  grep -F -x -f input | # the entries whose plurals appear
  sed -e 's/$/s/'     | # the plurals to remove
  grep -F -x -v -f - input
```

Comment: You don't need the first `grep` and you can avoid the second `sed` via `paste` (which is faster than any regex engine on the planet) e.g. `sed -n 's/s$//p' infile | grep -Fxf infile | paste -d s - /dev/null | grep -vFxf- infile` or, alternatively, `sed '/s$/!s/$/s/' infile | sort | uniq -d |  grep -vFxf- infile`

Answer (score 1):

```
#! /usr/bin/perl

use strict;

my %words = ();
my $index = 1;  # keep track of the order that words were read in

while (<>) {
  chomp;
  $words{$_} = $index++ 
}

# sort %words hash by value to print words in the same order
# that they were seen.
foreach (sort { $words{$a} <=> $words{$b} } keys %words) {
  my $word = $_;
  $word =~ s/s$//;
  next if ( ($word ne $_) && (defined $words{$word}) );
  print "$_\n";
}
```

Output:

```
frog
cat
dog
catfish
octopus
```